Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop in React
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function About(props) {
    const [theme,setTheme] = useState(null)

    function toggle(option){
        if(option==="light"){
            setTheme({
                color:"black",
                backgroundColor:"white",
                width:"90%",
                marginInline:"auto"

            })
            console.log(theme,option==="light");

            // return theme
        }else if(option==="dark"){
            setTheme({
                color:"white",
                backgroundColor:"black",
                width:"90%",
                marginInline:"auto"
            })
            console.log(theme,option==="light");
            // return theme

        }else{
            setTheme({
                color:"white",
                backgroundColor:"#032f3c",
                width:"90%",
                marginInline:"auto"
            })
            console.log(theme,option==="light");
            // return theme
        }

    }
  return (
    <div >
        {toggle(props.theme)}
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" >
            <div class="accordion-item" style={theme}>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample" >
                <div class="accordion-body" >
                    /content/
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

I am trying to change the theme of the page depending on what (props.theme) value is
but when i call the function toggle in return it 'say render too many times' but without calling function this functional component displays on the page with default values of bootstrap framework.

Each time this code runs {toggle(props.theme)} it immediately changes the theme, which triggers another render, which changes the theme again, etc.

understood thank You very much


Return statement invoks the toggle function directly:
{toggle(props.theme)}.
Every time this component renders, the toggle function gets called, that updates the state using setTheme.
As updating the state triggers a re-render, this end up in an infinite loop of rendering and state updates.
Using it in effect will resolve this.



import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function About(props) {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Set the initial theme based on props
        if (props.theme === 'light') {
            setTheme({
                color: 'black',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                width: '90%',
                marginInline: 'auto'
            });
        } else if (props.theme === 'dark') {
            setTheme({
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                width: '90%',
                marginInline: 'auto'
            });
        } else {
            setTheme({
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: '#032f3c',
                width: '90%',
                marginInline: 'auto'
            });
        }
    }, [props.theme]); // Only run this effect when props.theme changes

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div className="accordion-item" style={theme}>
                    <div
                        id="collapseOne"
                        className="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                        data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
                    >
                        <div className="accordion-body">/content/</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}



